# MySQL Delete removes wrong entry

Tags: mysql, sql-delete

I want to remove an entry of my 'Image' table.

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS removeImage$$

CREATE PROCEDURE removeImage(userID INT(10), imageID INT(10), OUT accesslevel INT(10))
BEGIN

SET accesslevel = 3;

IF accesslevel = 3 THEN
DELETE FROM Image
WHERE ImageID = imageID
limit 1;
END IF;

END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

When i call this procedure with

```
call removeImage(1, 32, @access);
SELECT @access;
```

@access returns 3 and

```
DELETE FROM Image
WHERE ImageID = imageID
limit 1;
```

removes the first entry of the table, but when I call this:

```
DELETE FROM Image WHERE ImageID = 12;
```

The right entry will be deleted.

So DELETE-part will be executed but it does something else then when I run it separately, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Perhaps you need to send the `ImageID as 12` while calling the procedure `call removeImage(1, 12, @access);`

Answer (score 0):

MySQL Server may be working case insensitive mode for table name, column name etc. In where clause imageID may refer to ImageID column of table. Try to  change parameter name in stored procedure imageID to p_imageID.